# Passing related model to vue 2.0 component

Tags: django, vue.js

I am building a vue.js frontend to a Django-based JSON REST API (which uses DREST - Dynamic Rest Views and DRF - Django Rest Framework).

In the vue frontend, I have an item list which iterates through an array with v-for using a single-item component. Basically:

```
<ul>
  <book v-for="book in books" 
     :book="book" 
     :author="authors*[book.author]">
   </book>
</ul>
```

The asterisk indicates the bit which is obviously incorrect at present. The idea is that the component receives two props, the primary object that is being displayed (book) and the secondary, referenced, object from the related model (author).

The data for the parent component contains an array of books and an array of authors which the API "side-loads", providing only the authors who are referenced in the page of books. In the book object, the author is referenced by their ID. An alternative might be to have the serializer nest the relevant author data in each JSON book object. But this would be less  efficient since some pages will only contain one or a few authors so there would be needless repetition.

Does vue.js have a way of getting the right author object from the author array (using the author UID that the book's author field contains), and passing it to the single-item (book) component?

Or should this be done in plain javascript (and if so how)?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use a method:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            authors: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        findAuthor (id) {
            return this.authors.find(x => x.id === id)
        }
    }
}

<ul>
  <book v-for="book in books" 
     :book="book" 
     :author="findAuthor(book.author)">
   </book>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. It's great you can call the function / method from the prop directive.. Thanks!